# Improve arduino for loop and void loop

Tags: arduino

I have wrote code for my Arduino project. It has a for loop. After for loop done there is a void loop.

I am expecting starting gap should reduce from 100 to 0 and remains constant. But when the code runs it goes 100 to 0 and reset the values again to 100. Then again values will go to 100 to 0. This time it remains 0.

My issue is why it takes two time to remain 0.What are the changes I should do to code to get expected output.

Expected output is only one loop. 100 is reducing to 0. then remain 0.

thank you.

Expected output is like this. Sine wave is come from a AC supply. Please neglect the shape of sine and assume it as a pulse (PWM).

[image]

Code:

```
int minGap = 0;//motor full speed gap
int pulseWidth = 10;//pulse lenght
int startGap = 100;//starting gap
int gapReduseRate = 1;//gap reduse rate
 
void setup() {
  // initialize digital pin LED_BUILTIN as an output.
  pinMode(3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(9, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(5, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(6, OUTPUT);
 
  for(int i=startGap ; i>minGap ; i=i-gapReduseRate){
      digitalWrite(3, HIGH); // turn the LED on (HIGH is the voltage level)
      digitalWrite(9, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(5, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(6, HIGH);// turn the LED on (HIGH is the voltage level)
      delayMicroseconds(pulseWidth);                       // wait for a second
      digitalWrite(3, LOW);    // turn the LED off by making the voltage LOW
      digitalWrite(9, LOW);
      digitalWrite(5, LOW);
      digitalWrite(6, LOW);// turn the LED off by making the voltage LOW
      delayMicroseconds(i);                      // wait for a second
    }
}
 
// the loop function runs over and over again forever
void loop() {
   digitalWrite(3, HIGH);   // turn the LED on (HIGH is the voltage level)
   digitalWrite(9, HIGH);
   digitalWrite(5, HIGH);
   digitalWrite(6, HIGH);// turn the LED on (HIGH is the voltage level)
   delayMicroseconds(pulseWidth);                       // wait for a second
   digitalWrite(3, LOW);    // turn the LED off by making the voltage LOW
   digitalWrite(9, LOW);
   digitalWrite(5, LOW);
   digitalWrite(6, LOW);// turn the LED off by making the voltage LOW
   delayMicroseconds(minGap);                      // wait for a second
}
```

Comment: You set startGap to 100, and after that, you never subtract anything from startGap. Why do you think it will go to 0?

Comment: @ocrdu I am assigning i to startGap value and reduce from it. Please look for loop

Comment: No, you're not. You''re not touching startGap after assigning startGap to i. You are decrementing i, not startGap.

Comment: @ocrdu but it doesn't affect  to the output. Does it ?

Comment: minGap does, and it is always 0. startGap is always 100. Have a close look at what you want to do and how each variable should behave doing what you want to do.

Comment: @ocrdu. yes minGap shouch be always 0. It should be a variable according to our use. Eg: In one case it can be 0 . Another case it can be 10.  It is a constant in one application. But changes when consider many applications. StartGap is act like the same. Don't ask why . I have attached image for you to understand more.

Comment: Please help me to stop looping in this code

Comment: If you only want to go through the for loop, and then do nothing, you should remove all code from the loop.